# How can I get this code to only output one link?

Tags: categories

This is the code I'm using to output the child categories of my posts as links.

```
<?php
$mycats = array(106, 107);
foreach (get_the_category() as $childcat) {
    foreach ($mycats as $mycat) {
        if (cat_is_ancestor_of($mycat, $childcat)) {
            echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">' . $childcat->cat_name . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My questions is, how can I get it to only output *one* link, when the post is in more than one child category? I tried adding a break command after the last line, but that didn't work. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `break` both `foreach` loops not just one, so add `break 2;` after the `echo`.

```
   $mycats = array(106, 107);
    foreach (get_the_category() as $childcat) {
        foreach ($mycats as $mycat) {
            if (cat_is_ancestor_of($mycat, $childcat)) {
                echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">' . $childcat->cat_name . '</a>';
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
```